# Why use _mm_malloc? (as opposed to _aligned_malloc, alligned_alloc, or posix_memalign)

Tags: c, memory-management, intel, dynamic-memory-allocation

There are a few options for acquiring an aligned block of memory but they're very similar and the issue mostly boils down to what language standard and platforms you're targeting.

C11

```
void * aligned_alloc (size_t alignment, size_t size)
```

POSIX

```
int posix_memalign (void **memptr, size_t alignment, size_t size)
```

Windows

```
void * _aligned_malloc(size_t size, size_t alignment);
```

And of course it's also always an option to align by hand.

Intel offers another option.

Intel

```
void* _mm_malloc (int size, int align)
void _mm_free (void *p)
```

Based on source code released by Intel, this seems to be the method of allocating aligned memory their engineers prefer but I can't find any documentation comparing it to other methods. The closest I found simply acknowledges that other aligned memory allocation routines exist.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/memory-management-for-optimal-performance-on-intel-xeon-phi-coprocessor-alignment-and

> To dynamically allocate a piece of aligned memory, use posix_memalign,
>   which is supported by GCC as well as the Intel Compiler. The benefit
>   of using it is that you don’t have to change the memory disposal API.
>   You can use free() as you always do. But pay attention to the
>   parameter profile:
>
> int posix_memalign (void **memptr, size_t align, size_t size);
>
> The Intel Compiler also provides another set of memory allocation
>   APIs. C/C++ programmers can use _mm_malloc and _mm_free to allocate
>   and free aligned blocks of memory. For example, the following
>   statement requests a 64-byte aligned memory block for 8 floating point
>   elements.
>
> farray = (float *)__mm_malloc(8*sizeof(float), 64);
>
> Memory that is allocated using _mm_malloc must be freed using
>   _mm_free. Calling free on memory allocated with _mm_malloc or calling _mm_free on memory allocated with malloc will result in unpredictable behavior.

The clear differences from a user perspective is that `_mm_malloc` requires direct CPU and compiler support and memory allocated with `_mm_malloc` must be freed with `_mm_free`. Given these drawbacks, what is the reason for ever using `_mm_malloc?` Can it have a slight performance advantage? Historical accident?

Comment: @alk There's no reason to be rude. If the answer is obvious to you then please explain.

Comment: It might sound rude, it isn't meant this way. It is a question, probably a bit sarcastic.

Comment: Perhaps I should have better asked why you think the document does not answer your question.... ;-)

Comment: @alk Hmmm... I'm just not seeing an answer in the linked doc... if it's there either my eyes or brain have fallen out of my head today (or both). Wait, did you read this whole question? Especially the last paragraph?

Comment: I'd go for "*performance*".

Comment: But you are right, the document does not answer your question. Please excuse my imputation. However the interesting part is the one about the functions accessing the "scalable"  memory pools, which use the same signature as the `_mm_*()` functions.

Comment: Btw, using `_mm_malloc` and `_mm_free` is still the most clean (doesn't need a bunch of `#ifdef`s) cross-platform solution till today.  Works on Linux, Windows and macOS with GCC, MinGW, Clang and MSVC.  Just need to include right headers.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Intel compilers support POSIX (Linux) and non-POSIX (Windows) operating systems, hence cannot rely upon either the POSIX or the Windows function. Thus, a compiler-specific but OS-agnostic solution was chosen.

C11 is a great solution but Microsoft doesn't even support C99 yet, so who knows if they will ever support C11.

**Update:** Unlike the C11/POSIX/Windows allocation functions, the ICC intrinsics include a deallocation function.  This allows this API to use a separate heap manager from the default one.  I don't know if/when it actually does that, but it can be useful to support this model.

*Disclaimer: I work for Intel but have no special knowledge of these decisions, which happened long before I joined the company.*

Comment: Oh, huh, that is in fact very simple and makes perfect sense! It's easy to get myopic about your own operating system and not realize these things.

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to take an existing C compiler which does not presently happen to use the identifiers `_mm_alloc` and `_mm_free` and define functions with those names which will behave as required.  This could be done either by having `_mm_alloc` function as a wrapper on `malloc()` which asks for a slightly-oversized allocation and constructs a pointer to the first suitably-aligned address within it that's at least one byte from the beginning, and storing the number of bytes skipped immediately before that address, or by having `_mm_malloc` request large chunks of memory from `malloc()` and then dispense them piecemeal.  In any case, the pointers returned by `_mm_malloc()` would not be pointers that `free()` would generally know how to do anything with; calling `_mm_free` would use the byte immediately preceding the allocation as an aid to finding the real start of the allocation received from `malloc`, and then pass that do `free`.

If an aligned-allocate function is allowed to use the internals of the `malloc` and `free` functions, however, that may eliminate the need for the extra layer of wrapping.  It's possible to write `_mm_alloc()`/`_mm_free()` functions which wraps `malloc`/`free` without knowing anything about their internals, but it requires that `_mm_alloc()` keep book-keeping information which is separate from that used by `malloc`/`free`.

If the author of an aligned-allocate function knows how `malloc` and `free` are implemented, it will often be possible to coordinate the design of all the allocation/free functions so that `free` can distinguish all kinds of allocations and handle them appropriately.  No single aligned-allocate implementation would be usable on all `malloc`/`free` implementations, however.

I would suggest that the most portable way to write code would probably be to select a couple of symbols that are not used anywhere else for your own allocate and free functions, so that you could then say, e.g.

```
#define a_alloc(align,sz) _mm_alloc((align),(sz))
#define a_free(ptr)  _mm_free((ptr))
```

on compilers that support that, or

```
static inline void *aa_alloc(int align, int size)
{
  void *ret=0;
  posix_memalign(&ret, align, size); // Guessing here
  return ret;
}
#define a_alloc(align,sz) aa_alloc((align),(sz))
#define a_free(ptr)  free((ptr))
```

on Posix systems, etc.  For every system it should be possible to define macros or functions that will yield the necessary behavior [I think it's probably better to use macros consistently than to sometimes use macros and sometimes functions, so as to allow `#if defined macroname` to test whether things are defined yet].

Answer (score 4):

_mm_malloc seems to have been created before there was a standard aligned_alloc function, and the need to use _mm_free is a quirk of the implementation.

My guess is that unlike when using posix_memalign, it doesn't need to over-allocate in order to guarantee alignment, instead it uses a separate alignment-aware allocator. This will save memory when allocating types with alignment different to the default alignment (typically 8 or 16 bytes).

Comment: If anything probably the opposite: `_mm_malloc` *could* work by over-allocating and leaving metadata before the memory it returns, making it incompatible with `free` when the standard allocator isn't overalignment-capable. `posix_memalign` is compatible with `free` so it can't do that. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_memalign.3.html shows that on GNU/Linux, all the aligned-alloc functions are compatible with `free`.  The obsolete `memalign` *doesn't* provide any guaranteed-safe way to free the resulting memory, and did on some systems over-alloc and align without saving the pointer.

Comment: In glibc, `_mm_malloc` is literally defined as a wrapper around `posix_memalign` (or `malloc` for `alignment==1`).  But yes your general argument is true that not being free-compatible is a result of having to do something special on old systems.  Or even on modern Windows aligned allocation functions still aren't compatible with free or delete, and do actually crash.