# How to use a char* into an for an api which takes char[]'s address?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory

The library which I intend to use is, io_submit.
Not to be confused with POSIX aio.

The iocb structure has a field, called as, aio_buf, which is the address( aligned) of a buffer.

On most examples on the internet, the way it has been shown is,

```
char data[4096];
struct iocb cb
cb.aio_buf = (uint64_t)data
```

Here is my problem:

There exists some other API already, which gives me aligned address. 
( specifically a kernel driver, which maps into my address space ).

Here is what I am able to do:

```
char **someBuffer = new char*[someCount];
// in a loop 
someBuffer[loopCounter] = valloc(aLenght)
memcpy(someBuffer[loopCounter], someAddress, aLenght);
...
...
...
cbs[someCount].aio_buf = (uint64_t)(someBuffer[loopCounter])
...
...
...
...
...
...
... // looping ends
...
... 
...
...
call io_submit.
```

Here is what I want to do:

I want to avoid the new, memcpy, calls.

I know that the address is already memory aligned which is given to me.

But some basic understanding is missing on my part.

I have tried using io_submit using the addresses, but I get back the error (-14) [bad address] in the io_getevents call.

How Have I tried:

cb.aio_buf = (uint64_t) someAddress;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612881/why-use-mm-malloc-as-opposed-to-aligned-malloc-alligned-alloc-or-posix-mem

Comment: @stark I do not want to use any allocation. The kernel code which runs in my process's context only, and always, maps memory aligned address into my process address space.

I am missing on some basic pointer understanding.

Comment: This `cb.aio_buf = (uint64_t)data` are you sure it's not `cb.aio_buf = (uint64_t *)data` ?  Which if so would make your code `cb.aio_buf = (uint64_t *) someAddress;`

Comment: @RichardCritten https://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/~vass/linux-aio.txt Line 62, example 2

Comment: Are you setting `aio_nbytes` to the correct value?

Comment: @Clearer Yes. I am setting it to the correct value.

Comment: You might get better answers if you could also show the declaration and documentation of the memory mapping kernel call.

Comment: @Sebastian The kernel driver simply vm_mmap into my address space. And I get to know the address by an ioctl into the driver.
As I have told, if I do a vmalloc on the address, and then do a memcpy, then give the address of the buffer into which I memcpy ied, then the io* calls work. I am missing something on pointers.

Comment: Is your mapped memory read-only, and io_submit tries to write? Or does the mapping not stay valid until io_submit is done using it (maybe asynchronously)?

Comment: @Sebastian No, that is not the case. Also, there is another ioctl which I have to call once I intend to inform the kernel module to to an unmap from the address space. And, I am not doing.